# Invalid argument when read() from timerfd

Tags: c, linux, debugging

I have a program that creates a timer using `timerfd_create()` and the timer is specified with an interval so that the process is notified regularly. Then this timer is registered to `epoll`. The error is **Invalid argument** when executing `read()` in the handler, and the `errno` is 22. This error appears when I run this program on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian, Linux 4.9.80), but everything is fine when I run it on my laptop (Arch, Linux 4.15.15).

The related codes are pasted below. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
void epset_reg(int epfd, int fd, u32 events)
{
    struct epoll_event ev;

    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.data.fd = fd;
    ev.events = events;
    if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev) < 0)
        handle_err("epoll_ctl");
}

int init_timer(u32 interval)
{
    int tfd;
    struct itimerspec tspec;

    /* specify the timer */
    tspec.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    tspec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    tspec.it_interval.tv_sec = interval;
    tspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    /* create timerfd */
    if ((tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0)) < 0)
        handle_err("timerfd_create");

    /* arm (start) the periodic timer */
    if (timerfd_settime(tfd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &tspec, NULL) < 0)
        handle_err("timerfd_settime");

    return tfd;
}

void handler(int tfd)
{
    u64 exp;

    /* THE ERROR ! */
    if (read(tfd, &exp, sizeof(exp)) < 0)
        handle_err("read");

    /* irrelevant parts */
}

int main()
{
    int epfd, tfd, sock, nfds, i;
    struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];

    /* create new epoll instance */
    if ((epfd = epoll_create1(0)) < 0)
        handle_err("epoll_create1");

    /* obtain timerfd */
    tfd = init_timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
    /* obtain socket to listen */
    sock = init_socket(CC_PORT);

    /* register sock and tfd to epoll set */
    epset_reg(epfd, tfd, EPOLLIN);
    epset_reg(epfd, sock, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);

    for (;;) {
        if ((nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1)) < 0)
            handle_err("epoll_wait");

        for (i = 0; i < nfds; ++i) {
            if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
                (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
                (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "epoll\n");
                close(events[i].data.fd);
                continue;
            }

            if (events[i].data.fd == tfd)
                handler(tfd);
            else if (events[i].data.fd == sock)
                accept_conn(sock, epfd);
            else
                handle_message(events[i].data.fd);
        }
    }
}
```

The complete program is hosted on https://github.com/iamlazynic/centralized_wlan/tree/master/cc inside [cc.c](https://github.com/iamlazynic/centralized_wlan/blob/master/cc/cc.c) and [main.c](https://github.com/iamlazynic/centralized_wlan/blob/master/cc/main.c).

Except for suggestion on this problem, it would be great if there is advice on how to debug in the situation. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: You're potentially reading 64 bytes into an 8-byte variable (`sizeof(exp) == 8` not 64).  It's usually better to do something like this `read(tfd, &exp, sizeof(exp))` to avoid that kind of mistake.

Comment: @jszakmeister I am sorry. I fixed that line in the question but in fact my original program is correct about this. I changed that line and made this mistake for some stupid reason when I pasted it here. But thank you for pointing it out.The error about `read()` isn't because of this.

Comment: No worries, but the code up there is still wrong. :-)  You're missing a paren after `sizeof(exp)`.

Comment: I wonder if you're running into a problem with `epoll()`.  An [article](https://idea.popcount.org/2017-03-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-22/) explains an interesting quirk of the API. 
 Look for the paragraph that starts with "epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_ADD) doesn't actually register a file descriptor."  And read the paragraph after too.  I wonder if it's possible that you're receiving an event for a handle that's closed due to epoll()'s implementation?  To be honest, it's disappointing that epoll works this way. :-(

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're u64 is actually 8 bytes?  The man page for timerfd_create() says that if the buffer is too small, you can get `EINVAL` (which is what you're seeing).  I can see in your original code you typedef'd u64 to an `unsigned long int`.  But if your Pi is a 32-bit processor, then `sizeof(u64)` is 4, not 8.  You would have to typedef it to an `unsigned long long int` on a 32-bit platform.  Consider using stdint.h to avoid these issues and use uint64_t instead--it already does the hard work of figuring out how to typedef it correctly. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister This is the problem and you are totally right! I changed the `typedef` to using `uint64_t` and so on, and now the program is error free. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great!  I went ahead and added it as an answer, not so much for points, but so that others can see there was a resolution.  Glad it's working for you!  And I learned about some interesting quirks of epoll() in the process. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working through this, we discovered that the typedef for a `u64` was wrong and the code was attempting to read to few bytes, which will result in an `EINVAL` error code.  The typedef was:

```
typedef unsigned long int u64;
```

But on a 32-bit system, this is likely on 4 bytes in size.  Instead, we used stdint.h and the `uint64_t` type (which takes care to typedef things a little more carefully for the platform you're using) and now has the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the synopsis of read function.

ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);

The second is the buf pointer and the third is the size to read. You set the size to 64 bytes. But the pointer is the address of exp(8bytes) which is assigned at stack.  I think it can corrupt the stack.